# build with react-router doesn't show my app ( empty page )

Tags: reactjs, build, react-router

I built my app but I don't have anything on screen.

I used react-router for the path between my pages but nothing is displayed...

my app need to be in a subfolder : folder/subfolder/subfolder as main link.

I dont know where i'm wrong

Here is my route:

```
<Router basename="/">
<div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/scene01" component={Scene01}/>
</div>
</Router>
```

my package.json:

```
"name": "impermo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/folder/subfolder/subfolder/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Switch` from `react-router`

From [ReactTraining.com](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

> A `<Switch>` looks through its children `<Route>`s and renders the first one that matches the current URL.

```
<Router basename="/">
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/scene01" component={Scene01}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the main js file? Also, have you reviewed the console to see if there is an error?

Comment: I looked in the console, fix some error, now my app is displayed thanky you, but if I refresh my page i got a 404 error page

Comment: I edited my answer. the next step would be to remove the basename as it may conflict with your homepage.

Comment: well if i remove the basename, it's not working again

Comment: it's only working if i put basename="/folder/subfolder/subfolder" but like that i can't refresh my page :/